# How to create a watch folder in python to import .csv files automatically

Tags: python, python-import, read.csv

For my project, I want to import a .csv file as soon as it is dropped in a certain folder. I want to make that folder a watch folder so that whenever someone drops a .csv file into that folder, it is automatically imported into my project instead of me running the code to import it every time.

I want to automate this process of data injection as new .csv files will be used every day. Is there is any other way to automate this process? I am a newbie so looking for possible suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.